# How to update the same element that's in another class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update the same element that's in another class. So currently the `user_friendlist` and `activeusers` are both are arrays of strings and it checks if both arrays contain a same entry. If that's the case then I also want to update the same element so could be  [0] or [1] for both different classes.

But I don't know how to do this, I know how to do it for one class but how could I do this for the other class while checking the first one. And that's also the same element as the other one so both element0 for example but then for both different classnames.

```js
//Display if a player is online and if he is also in the players friendlist
let friendOnlineNames        = document.getElementsByClassName('friendlistentry')
let friendlistactivitystatus = document.getElementsByClassName('friendlistactivitystatus')

const filteredArray = user_friendlist.filter(value => activeusers.includes(value));

console.log(filteredArray)

let friendNamesToString = filteredArray.toString()

console.log(friendNamesToString)

for (let i = 0; i < friendOnlineNames.length; i++) {
  if (friendOnlineNames[i].innerHTML == friendNamesToString) {
    friendlistactivitystatus[i].innerHTML = "Online"
  }
}
```

```html
<h4 id="friendlisttext">Friends list
  <%= user.friendlist.length%>/20 </h4>
<div id="friendlistblock">
  <l class="friendlistentry">
    <%=user.friendlist[0]%>
  </l>
  <br/><br/>
  <form method="POST">
    <h2 class="friendlistactivitystatus"></h2>
    <input class="friendlistentryinput" name="friend0" label="friend0" type="text" value="<%=user.friendlist[0]%>">
    <button class="friendlistentrymessagebutton" formaction="friend0message">Send Message</button>
    <button class="friendlistentryprofilebutton" formaction="friend0profile">View Profile</button>
  </form>
  <l class="friendlistentry">
    <%=user.friendlist[1]%>
  </l> <br/><br/>
  <form method="POST">
    <h2 class="friendlistactivitystatus"></h2>
    <input class="friendlistentryinput" name="friend1" label="friend1" type="text" value="<%=user.friendlist[1]%>">
    <button class="friendlistentrymessagebutton" formaction="friend1message">Send Message</button>
    <button class="friendlistentryprofilebutton" formaction="friend1profile">View Profile</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean in jsfiddle for example?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some minimal HTML

Comment: `filteredArray.toString()` is returning a comma-separated string. I'd be surprised if `friendOnlineNames[i].innerHTML == friendNamesToString` was ever true, because `friendOnlineNames` is likely a _single_ name, not the full comma-separated value. So you probably want to detect if `friendNamesToString` _includes_ `friendOnlineNames[i].innerHTML`, not if they're equal. But at that point, you might as well use `filteredArray` instead of the string.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Thanks that part works, but now how do I update the same element for the class friendlistactivitystatus?

Comment: your question is too abstract. if you really want to have answers give a micro example of what you want to do, as it is recommended in the guidelines of this site which obviously you have not read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it is  inside https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `<l>` is not a valid HTML5 tag....

Comment: Yeh your right made a typo there it seems

Comment: I dont know how else I could explain this you @MisterJoJo all I want is to update the same element index that came from the match of the two arrays but then for the other class. So it should for example if the first match was element0 for the class friendOnlineNames then it should update element0 aswell for the class friendlistactivitystatus. Its not really rocket science it seems very clear to me.

Comment: first explain why `"message": "ReferenceError: user_friendlist is not defined",`

Comment: Its a array of strings to test it you can give it any value that you desire because it does not really matter in this case. As long as both arrays have a similar value so you can test it. @MisterJojo

Comment: @Mister Jojo What do you mean? this is one of them: <li class="friendlistentry">
        <%=user.friendlist[0]%>
      </li>

Comment: I'm not the one to convince, and your question still remains abstract. until you clarify it better it will go unanswered. In the meantime, your question goes down the page rankings and no one ever reads it again.